# Passing Record ID from Controller.js to Controller.apxc for SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-aura-components, aura, parameters

I'm trying to pass a Id parameter that I have verified through console.log()

I am successfully getting the Id but I am unsuccessful in receiving the Id and using it for the WHERE id=:id in a SOQL statement.

It keeps saying 0 query results.

Please guide me!

**Controller.js**

```
({
doInit : function(component, event){
  var action = component.get("c.getStatus");
  var currentId = component.get("v.recordId");  
    action.setParams({
        recordId : currentId
    });
    console.log(currentId);

  action.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var state = response.getState();
    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
        $A.log(response);
      component.set("v.currentStep", response.getReturnValue());
    }
    else {
      console.log("Failed with state" + state);
    }
  })
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

onStepChange : function(component, event) {
    var action = component.get("c.saveStatus");

    var currentId = component.get("v.recordId");  
      action.setParams({
        recordId : currentId
        });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
      var state = response.getState();

      if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
        var currentStep = component.get("v.currentStep");   
        component.set(currentStep, response.getReturnValue());
      }
      else {
        console.log("Failed with state" + state);
      }
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(action)
}})
```

Controller.apxc

```
    public with sharing class ApexController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static list<Object__c> getStatus(Id recordId){

        return[SELECT Id, status__c FROM Object__c WHERE Id=:recordId];
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Object__c saveStatus(Object__c newStatus){
        upsert newStatus;
        return newStatus;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you debug and see what you are getting as recordId in the apexcontroller, if you do not get anything try changing Id to string and see if the query returns a list

Comment: Try adding debug statements to your Apex controller. For starters, I don't see where `getStatus(Id recordId)` which BTW you've not declared in your Apex Controller as variables will return a list<Object__c> (or pass one), which ever you're trying to do. That statement just doesn't look correct to me. Would seem that you'd need a get statement of some kind.